# To find the Value of $\tan A + \cot A$, if the value of $\sin A + \cos A$ is given

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

To Find -
$$\tan A + \cot A$$

Given,
$$\sin A + \cos A = \sqrt2$$

My progress as far -

1st way-
$$\Rightarrow \sin A = \sqrt2  - \cos A$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan A = \frac{\sqrt2 - \cos A}{\cos A}$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan A = \frac{ \sqrt 2 }{\cos A } - 1$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan A + \cot A =\frac{ \sqrt 2 }{\cos A} -1 + \cot A $$

and the 2nd way as -

$$(\sin A + \cos A)^2 = 2$$
$$\sin ^2 A + \cos ^2 A + 2\sin A\cos A = 2 $$
$$\Rightarrow 2\sin A\cos A=1$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin A\cos A=\frac12$$

As we can see the first way is unable to give an answer in absolute Real Number, and the second way doesn't go even near to what is required to proof.

I know few trigonometry identities as per my textbook, those are

- $\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A = 1$
- $1 + \cot^2 A = \csc^2 A$
- $\tan^2A + 1 = \sec^2 A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan{A}+\cot{A}=\frac{1}{\sin{A}\cos{A}}=\frac{2}{(\sin{A}+\cos{A})^2-1}=2$$

Comment: didn't get your 3rd step $$\frac{2}{(sin A + cos A)^2 -1}$$ How was that?

Comment: @Abhas Kumar Sinha $\frac{1}{\sin{A}\cos{A}}=\frac{2}{2\sin{A}\cos{A}}=\frac{2}{\sin^2A+2\sin{A}\cos{A}+\cos^2A-1}=\frac{2}{(\sin{A}+\cos{A})^2-1}.$

Comment: gotcha, quite difficult to do in a single step.

Comment: But it's exactly like I thought.

Comment: Can you solve this in my first way?

Comment: I think it's very hard to end your first way. Maybe to calculate a value of $A$ before. If so it works, but I think it's a  long  solution.

Comment: How you are able to think how to approach to the solution? you did in a second before I posted my question....

Comment: I tried to get cot and tan in the first way but it doesn't happen to get answer = 2 even after going to multiple different directions to solve the problem

Comment: From the given we obtain $\cos\left(A-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=1$, which gives $A=\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$. Thus, $\tan{A}=\cot{A}=1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you said now. how $$\cos (A - \frac{pi}{4})$$?

Comment: Okay, you are using radians, I haven't studied it

Comment: You can write also $\cos\left(A-45^{\circ}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\sin{A}+\cos{A}).$

Comment: yea, gotcha, how to do it

Comment: I've one question in my mind, I don't think that i can ask it in the stackexchange, What are practical relations of trigonometric proofs through trigonometric identities in practical geometry?

Comment: Do trigonometric proofs help in practical or just they are valueless?

Comment: It helps of course, but it depends on the problem, which you need to solve.

Comment: can you give few examples how they help?

Comment: for example - $$(\sec A + \tan A)^2 = \frac{1 + \sin A}{1 - \sin A}$$. How they help practically and geometerically ? I don't see a right angled triangle where this equation is useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71004/discussion-between-abhas-kumar-sinha-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is actually what helps here. Note:

$$\begin{align}\tan A+\cot A&=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}+\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}\\&=\frac{\sin^2 A+\cos^2 A}{\sin A\cos A}\\&=\frac{1}{\sin A\cos A}\\&=\frac{1}{1/2}\\&=2\end{align}$$

Comment: how sinA.cosA = $ \frac{1}{2}$ ??

Comment: Didn't *you* already derive that yourself, as your second attempt, which "doesn't go even near to what is required to proof". Umm... actually... it does!

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha when you did, $(\sin A+\cos A)^2=1+2\sin A\cos A$, you ended up with $\sin A\cos A=\dfrac12$, in your second approach :)

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha, hope you've managed to clarify it...

Comment: @AwnonBhowmik yea, you've perfectly clarified everything, just questions how you are able to think this much in seconds? :) +1 upvote from me

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\tan A+\cot A&=\dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A}+\dfrac{\cos A}{\sin A}\\&=\dfrac{\sin^2A+\cos^2A}{\sin A\cos A}\\&=\dfrac1{\sin A\cos A}\\&=\dfrac2{2\sin A\cos A}\\&=\dfrac2{(\sin A+\cos A)^2-1}\\&=\dfrac2{(\sqrt2)^2-1}\\&=2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos\frac {\pi}4=\sin\frac {\pi}4=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$. Hence what you have got is $$\cos\frac {\pi}4\sin A+\sin\frac {\pi}4\cos A=1$$ or $\sin\Big(A+\frac {\pi}4\Big)=1$. Can you solve from here?

Comment: $$\cos \frac {pi}{4} = \sin \frac{pi}{4}$$ Did't studied about it.

Comment: $\frac {\pi}4$ is same as $45^{\circ}$. Don't you know how to find the sine and cosine values for this angle? If not, note that the right angled triangle with one of its acute angle equal to $45^{\circ}$ is isosceles.

Comment: how $ \frac{pi}{4} = 45$ degrees, pi is irrational and irrational / rational is always a irrational (also given if rational number is not takes = 0)

Comment: Their units are different. Sorry for not being more specific. Actually $\frac {\pi}4$ radians = $45$ degrees.

Comment: Haven't studied radians, I'm 10th grade,

Comment: gotcha, the circumference/diameter is constant, so if a circle is divided into 8 parts. the is equivalent to pi/4?

Comment: Yep, correct. Now you got it. Otherwise just replace $\frac {\pi}4$ by $45^{\circ}$ in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use $\sin^2A=\sqrt{1-\cos^2A}$

Equation transform into$$\sin A+\sqrt{1-\sin^2A}=\sqrt2$$

Which is quadratic equation and easy to solve

Comment: what are you trying to say? I've to find tanA + cotA without using tables, only identities

Comment: Find the value of sin A from the equation , then evaluate cos A using identity and then evaluate tanA +cotA